# php artisan migrate giving me error in Lumen

Tags: php, lumen, laravel-artisan, migrate

When I am trying to migrate in Lumen it giving me following error

In `Connection.php line 664:`

```
  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where t  
  able_schema = authors and table_name = migrations)
```

In `Connector.php line 68:`

```
  could not find driver
```

I am using a apache2 on ubuntu 16.

Comment: What sort of database do you use?

Comment: MySQL database I am using currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by updating PHP version.
I was using php7.0 .
I updated it to php7.2 .
Lumen required minimum php7.1 .

I used following commands

> sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysql
>
> php artisan cache:clear

Answer (score 0):

If you use `MySQL` database, please make sure your `pdo_mysql` php extension has been enabled.

Comment: Yes, it was enabled